What's "I think I could have them" mean in this context?
This context comes from the book "The Outliers" my Malcolm Gladwell.

"I have never met anybody like me or never seen even an indication
that there is somebody who actually has  better powers of
comprehension. Never seen it and I don't think I am going to.   I
Could –my mind is open to the possibility. If anyone should challenge
me.'Oh, I think that I am smarter than you are' —I think I could have
them."

If have means something similar to defeat or cheat, the sentence doesn't make much sense because it starts off with "I Could –my mind is open to the possibility", which would suggest that "there are certain circumstances in which he would admit that someone's smarter than him".
informal
cheat or deceive (someone).
"I realized I'd been had"
Similar:
trick
fool
deceive
cheat
dupe
take in
outwit
(Oxford Languages)

Is "Could" really capitalized like that in the text?

It looks as though Oh, I think that I am smarter than you are is a quote that Gladwell is putting into the mouth of his hypothetical challenger: it’s the actual challenge.
In any event, yes the expression to have someone as used here does mean “defeat someone.”
The entire passage reads much more like the transcript of spoken remarks than like carefully a crafted bit of writing. Perhaps that was the effect he was aiming for?
His “I could—“ seems to be the interrupted beginning of a thought that immediately changes direction somewhat. As though he were originally going say something like “I could possibly encounter someone who would try to challenge my prowess,” but shifted his hypothesizing away from his possible encountering and to that challenger’s possible utterance.

He's simply continuing his claim that he's the smartest person around. The statement that he's open to the possibility that someone is smarter than him is just a diversion. But since he considers this a very remote possibility, he believes that if someone challenges him, he can defeat them. So "have them" means "defeat them", as you say.
It's a confusing, stream of consciousness paragraph where he doesn't make this back-and-forth reasoning clear.

OP has asked the meaning of the phrase "could have them" in the following context :

If anyone should challenge me.'Oh, I think that I am smarter than you are' —I think I could have them."

The speaker is Christopher Langan. He confidently states that he has never met anyone smarter than himself with better powers of comprehension and believes it is highly unlikely to find such a person. However, he remains open to the possibility that someone might challenge him in the future by claiming to be smarter. In such a case, he is ready to take on the challenge and compete with them.
Here, the phrase "have them" means:

have.
to gain control of or advantage over


Christopher Michael Langan is an American horse rancher and former bar bouncer, widely known for his exceptionally high IQ and for being listed in the Guinness Book of Records in its high IQ section. Langan was featured in Malcolm Gladwell's Outliers: The Story of Success (2008), where Gladwell explored why Langan's extraordinary intelligence had not translated into greater success in life.

Source: Wikipedia
